# Display Array content on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button, addeventlistener

I’m a beginner in coding and happen to come across this problem I can’t solve.

I know the issue could be in how I’m using the showBtn variable at the bottom to call the function on ‘click’.

So far when I click the button, it adds the random name to the button instead of displaying on the container with the Id of #name. Thoughts?

```js
let displayName = document.querySelector("#name");
let showBtn = document.querySelector("#button");

let namesArr = [
  "Edward",
  "Rigo",
  "Kevin",
  "Alden",
  "Jeffrey",
  "Maria",
  "Nova",
  "Abby",
];

let nameCalling = () => {
  displayName.innerHTML = namesArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * namesArr.length)];
};

showBtn.addEventListener("click", nameCalling);
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<button id="button"> Add name </button>
```

Comment: It is not so clear? what exactly is the problem? Please be specific...

Comment: I want to the random name from the array to display on html Div instead of it displaying on the button. When I click the button, the name appears inside of the button.

Comment: Made code runnable and it is working as expected. Have a look...